# How to apply multiple tax rate on the basis of row total(sale price) in magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento-1.9

In magento 1.9, I have to change the tax rate as per product value. This means if product value < 1000 then apply 5% tax rate and if it is >= 1000 then apply 18% tax rate.

Now it's not possible to apply tax on the basis of price, it is based on customer and country.

How may I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't have this configurable via admin panel so your only way would be to hook (via Magento event observer) to some event close to `sales_quote_collect_totals_before` and set the taxes there. The bad part about this is there will be no indication how this works (from the admin user perspective) so please make sure to document this correctly.